# Runtime error in Migratory Birds in Hackerrank

Tags: python

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/migratory-birds/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen
i tried to solve this problem
this is my code

```
def migratoryBirds(arr):
    freq = {}
    for i in arr:
        if i in freq:
            freq[i]+=1
        else :
            freq[i]=1
    v=list(freq.values())
    k=list(freq.keys())
    Maxkey=list()
    for i in v:
        if v[i]==max(v):
            Maxkey.append(k[i])
    print(Maxkey)
    return min(Maxkey)
```

in some cases it give me runtime error

Comment: Please be specific about the error.

Comment: input
10
2 4 3 2 3 1 2 1 3 3
Expected Output
3
this is the testcase where i get runtime error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is little change is required in second for loop.
You should use

```
for i in range(len(v)):
    if v[i]==max(v):
        Maxkey.append(k[i])
```

Instead of just

```
for i in v:
    if v[i]==max(v):
        Maxkey.append(k[i])
```

And you will not face that error.

Comment: thank u alot , it works now
can u explain the difference  please or more explanation

Comment: you just print the value of i and v[i] of your for loop. You will realise that i is getting actual values of list v, not indices of the values of v, and as mentioned in question values will always be in between 1 to 5. So your i is getting values only between 1 to 5. And the remaining elements (with index more than 5) are not considered. So you getting wrong answer. I hope you get it. I can't explain much better as i am new here. You just print values at each step and you will realise it by yourself.

Comment: no ur explanation is great i got it , thank u